# Calculating the mean value of a poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

I have a set of three observations taken from a poisson distribution:

- The probability of event *e* occurring at a frequency of 0 is 2.959%
- The probability of event *e* occurring at a frequency of 1 is 10.419%
- The probability of event *e* occurring at a frequency of 2 is 18.337%

Given this information only, is there any way to calculate this distribution's mean value?

---

If this is possible, and I have even less information from the same distribution:

- The probability of event *e* occurring at a frequency of either 0, 1, or 2 is 31.715%

Is it still possible to calculate the mean?

Comment: Poisson observations are integers, but these seem to be $P(X=0),P(X=1),P(X=2)$ respectively. If that's the case, the distribution of $X$ cannot be Poisson.

Comment: For a Poisson RV, $P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda},$ so $-\ln[P(X=0)] = \lambda.$ Also, $P(X=1)/P(X=0) = \lambda.$ It's Sumday morning before coffee, but I don't get the same value of $\lambda$ both ways. Are your 'probabilities' supposed to be exact, or are they estimates based on a small bit of data?

Comment: The code that I wrote to calculate this was also done on Sunday morning without coffee, so I fear there is an error in it... Your answer is very helpful though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given this information only, is there any way to calculate this distribution's mean value?

Yes. The Poisson probability mass function is: $P(x; \lambda)=\tfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$ for $x=0,1,2,3,...$. It only has one parameter so you only need one data point to estimate $\lambda$. With multiple points you can estimate the coefficient which provides the best fit. The Binned Least-Squares Fit method illustrated in [this stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25828558/2228339) gives pretty much what you want. I've adopted the code from that post to work with your example and with the case of starting with probabilities.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import poisson

bins = [0,1,2]
entries = [0.02959, 0.10419, 0.18337]

plt.bar(x = bins, height = entries, label = "Data")

def fit_function(k, lamb):
    '''poisson function, parameter lamb is the fit parameter'''
    return poisson.pmf(k, lamb)

# fit with curve_fit
parameters, cov_matrix = curve_fit(fit_function, bins, entries, p0=3)

# plot poisson-deviation with fitted parameter
x_plot = np.arange(0, 6)

plt.plot(
    x_plot,
    fit_function(x_plot, *parameters),
    marker='o', linestyle='',
    color= "red",
    label=f'Best fit:  λ = {round(parameters[0],4)}',
)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image: Best fit results]

> If this is possible, and I have even less information from the same distribution:
>   The probability of event e occurring at a frequency of either 0, 1, or 2 is 31.715%

Yes. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(0,1,2;\lambda)&=P(0;\lambda)+P(1;\lambda)+P(2;\lambda)\\
&=\tfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^0}{0!} + \tfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^1}{1!} + \tfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^2}{2!}\\
&=e^{-\lambda} +e^{-\lambda} \lambda + \tfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^2}{2}\\ \\
\text{Solve:  } \;\;
&e^{-\lambda} +e^{-\lambda} \lambda + \tfrac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^2}{2}=0.37
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!